# Azure SQL Data Warehouse and Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, azure, data-warehouse, azure-synapse

Does anybody know if/when we will be able to use Entity Framework with the Azure SQL Data Warehouse?  I have searched high and low and cannot seem to find anything other than a question posted on MSDN in Auguts 2015 saying:

> "We have not yet completed our certification for the Entity Framework"

EF7 Documentation doesn't seem to make any mention of it either.

Answer (score 2):

Azure SQL Data Warehouse doesn't currently support the Entity Framework. We are working to close this gap as soon as possible.

You can vote for this feature on our feedback page:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse